# How to run a code from current database and apply it on another database without opening it?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007, I have created an auto 'dynamic table linker' program (VBA) in the Frontend database and I would like to run this code and apply it to the Backend database without opening it (or in the background without user knowing).

My current approach is to autoopen the backend database and run the program on startup from the backend. However, this will run everytime when you open the backend.

I only want to run the program when it is redirected from the frontend and possibly hide this from the users when it runs. Is there any possible way to solve this requirement?

Clarification: I need to run the prexisting code on frontend and apply it to backend, that is to eliminate code duplication.

Comment: OK, I'm confused: you say you want to 'run this program on the Backend', and then you say 'The code should run from the Frontend'. Which is it? Why would you want to run a table linker on the backend? Backends typically never need to link to a frontend or other backends. Please simplify your question, and clarify what it is that you want to know.

Comment: @kismert I need to run the prexisiting code on the front end apply it to the backend. Yes typically the backend should not have linked tables, but for my company previous developers have connected the backend to some sort of external file that holds static table values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is what I would do (there are lots of relinking examples on-line, so I won't show any details here):

Original Code:

```
Public Sub RelinkTables(sOldLink As String, sNewLink As String)
    Dim oLinkDb As DAO.DataBase
    Set oLinkDb = CurrentDb
    ' do your linking for oLinkDb
```

New Code:

```
Public Sub RelinkTables(oLinkDb As DAO.DataBase, sOldLink As String, sNewLink As String)
    ' do your linking for oLinkDb
```

Call for frontend:

```
RelinkTables(CurrentDb, "OldLinkPath",  "NewLinkPath")
```

Remote call for backend:

```
Dim objAccess As New Access.Application
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\Path\Backend.accdb"
RelinkTables(objAccess.CurrentDb, "OldLinkPath",  "NewLinkPath")
```

This way, you have a single routine, `RelinkTables()`, that can relink for any database given to it. You still have to open the backend to relink, but this can't be helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following code in the frontend database.

`Sub ReLink
    Dim objAccess As New Access.Application
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\server\routetobackend\nameofbackenddatabase.accdb"
    objAccess.Eval "Function_to_relink('parameter')"
End Sub`

Where `Function_to_relink` is a function in the backend database,

Other info that could be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221161%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Manuel, your code runs a function on the backend. But, after reading the clarifications, I now think Jabberbyter wants to run code on the _frontend_ that manipulates the backend.